# Is it ever acceptable to prod a user into accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

I've seen a lot of questions with good solid answers that have been upvoted repeatedly (even questions where the asker has commented on an answer and basically said that it helped them solve their problem) but the asker never officially marks any answer as the one that helped them.  Is there an approved way to let the asker know that they should do this?

Also as a personal curiosity, I was awarded a bounty yesterday but when you look at [the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-do-i-turn-off-the-cellular-radio-without-disabling-bluetooth/7223#7223) it doesn't appear to have been marked as having an answer.  Is this the way questions work when there's a bounty attached to them or did the asker simply award me the bounty but fail to mark the answer as correct?

Comment: I believe the bounty goes to the highest upvoted answer automatically if no answer is selected by the user.

Comment: @Bryan Denny - Yeah, after seven days it's supposed to award half of the bounty to the highest voted answer.  But the asker gave me the full bounty without marking my answer as correct.

Comment: There have been several discussions about this at http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Let me see if I can find some and distill out the consensus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consensus seems to be that there's only so much we can and should do for new users. An awful lot of the time they're just "drive-by" askers who will get their answer (perhaps) and be gone, never to contribute to the site. There's no point in spending so much time on them.

For myself, I just try to remind people who find their own answer to post it as such and "accept" it, so that other people with the same issue will see the solution.

I think occasionally reminding users that they should accept the answer that worked for them is okay. If you're seen as a person who does it habitually, however, people may start flagging your comments.

Here's some relevant links:

- [Reminding new users of accept/upvote "duty"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty)
- [Is it bad form to prompt new questioners to formally accept your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/is-it-bad-form-to-prompt-new-questioners-to-formally-accept-your-answer)
- [Getting new users to accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/getting-new-users-to-accept-answers)

Comment: I would only remind users who have shown signs they are going to stick around. Reminding a drive-by user isn't useful.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, I was going to ask about that as I'm sort of in that situation right now. Although I figure he'll get around to it sometime :)